# reverse phrase search in zend lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, full-text-search, zend-lucene

Basically I have two tables *Location* and *city*, The city has city_name and country_code. location_name field from location table has locations. I want to find the location country.

My table structure.

City table

```
City

country_code   city_name
US             Kansas city
.........
(thousands of world country cities)
```

Location table

```
Location

location_name
Kansas city, mo
Kansas city
Kansas city, us
uSA, Kansas city
etc...
```

So I Indexed the two fields(country_code and city_name) in city table using Zend Lucene search. I will get the location name from table location and search against the Lucene index using keyword query.

I found lots of matched because of the term "city". So decided to change it phrase search. phrase search like "Kansas city, mo" this, but I found no result. So I realized I want to search the "Kansas city" against keyword "Kansas city, mo". **Is that possible to do reverse search or anyway to do relationship with location table index and find the country code**.